# What Microsoft Graph root resources to use while sending GET request to OneDrive API from an Azure registered web application?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have an enterprise application which was registered in the Azure portal, the application is able to get an access token by issuing OAuth2.0 request, my question is what is the exact GET request it should send to start interacting with the OneDrive resource?
Should I register it under a specific AD group in order for it to have the right permissions? Please advise on how to get to a state where this app can interact with the OneDrive API, upload and get files from a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the exact GET request it should send to start interacting
>   with the OneDrive resource?

You can get started from the [OneDrive API for Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onedrive-concept-overview)

> Should I register it under a specific AD group in order for it to have the right permissions?

No need specific AD group. Just to grant the permission for Graph follow the following steps:

1. Navigate to your app in the add [application](https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps) list.
2. Click the **Configure** and then permissions under the API access.
3. Click the **Add** to add "**Microsoft Graph**".
4. Check the permission on SharePoint/OneDrive such as "**Create, edit, and delete items and lists in all site collections/ Read and write user files/ Read user files**" and then **Save**. Then click the **Grant Permission** to let the permission take effect.